# Errors when testing facebook application

Tags: facebook

I am trying to test my application on facebook. But i keep getting the following errors:

Errors while loading page from application

> CSS Error (line 35 char 17): Error in parsing value for property.: 'font-style'  Declaration dropped.
>
> FBML Error (line 53): illegal tag "body" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 54): illegal attr ";" in tag "div". Attribute names can only contain alphanumeric characters, underscores, and hyphens.FBML Error (line 87): illegal tag "object" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 88): illegal tag "param" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 89): illegal tag "param" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 90): illegal tag "embed" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 214): illegal tag "object" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 215): illegal tag "param" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 216): illegal tag "param" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 218): illegal tag "embed" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 226): illegal tag "object" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 227): illegal tag "param" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 228): illegal tag "param" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 230): illegal tag "embed" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 248): illegal tag "object" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 249): illegal tag "param" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 250): illegal tag "param" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 252): illegal tag "embed" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 260): illegal tag "noscript" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 297): illegal tag "noscript" under "fb:canvas"
>
> FBML Error (line 311): illegal tag "noscript" under "fb:canvas"

Please try again later. We appreciate your patience as the developers of Hello World App
and Facebook resolve this issue. Thanks!

I am unable to understand where i am going wrong. I have written a simple code to display hello world as follows. Even that is not working.

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Please help me out with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBML does not allow certain tags. These tags include `<noscript>`, `<embed>`, and `<body>`. That's why you're seeing these errors. You also appear to have some invalid markup that is causing some of these errors as well.

You have two options:

1. Remove these elements from your page. (The body tag is not necessary. Noscript is not necessary because users must have js enabled to use facebook. Embed can probably be replaced with fb:swf assuming that it is used for flash content.)
2. Run your application as an iFrame application instead (The toggle for this is on the developer settings page).

I recommend looking into the benefits and drawbacks of #2 before taking that route. Specifically, you will need to use XFBML if you wish to use FBML features, and you may need to workaround the Safari browser's cookie restrictions.

Your sample PHP code should work fine, so for that example there is probably a different problem occurring there.

Good luck!

Comment: the same error persistes even when i write just the simple hello world application (code shown above)

any idea where i am going wrong?

Comment: There is a sample application that I am looking at which uses the body tag but does not generate errors. When I pull the project from github, I receive those errors. Any idea why?